# Debug API in TypeScript with Angular 12 via Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot find a solution from SO.

How to debug and check `hello` below?

```
getHero(): void {
  const id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') !, 10);
  this.heroService.getHero(id)
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/roynrxqmenv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-detail%2Fhero-detail.component.ts

It shows `undefined` like below, but actually has value,
[image]

Any idea?

Similarly, how to debug the returned value for `getHero` below.
the `h` below doesn't display anything.

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Hero>(url).pipe(
    tap(h => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(`getHero id=${id}`))
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/roynrxqmenv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero.service.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to wrap the single line statement in the callback function with `{}`

```
getHero(): void {
  const id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') !, 10);
  this.heroService.getHero(id)
    .subscribe(hero => {
      // debugger;
      this.hero = hero;
    });
}
```

This would allow you to place breakpoints in browsers at the right spot.

You could also place a `debugger` in there, just in case.

Comment: do you mean break one line into two lines?

Comment: I meant to add curly braces `{}` around your single line of code in your callback function body just so that it's easier to place breakpoints in browsers.